# mu4e query search for emails larger than certain size

Tags: search, email, mu4e

I've looked in all the examples given in [queries](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Queries.html#Queries) of mu4e email but couldn't find an option that returns all emails larger than a certain size (for example 10MB). I think this is relevant if one is trying to free some space from his mailbox. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a size range:

```
size:10M..100M
```

or:

```
size:10M..
```

Note that the manual you linked to is for `mu4e`, and only presents a subset of all the possible `mu` queries you can use. The complete list is provided in the manpage for `mu-query` (or `mu-find`), which you can read from Emacs via `M-x man <ENTER> mu-query`.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I added a short note on where to find more information!

Comment: FYI I'm the user24002. Your answer works well, although `size:10M..` returns a `error in process filter: mu4e-error-handler: Error 13: parse error in query`, and in my system it is `mu-find` and not `mu-query` that gives me the manual full list.

Comment: `size:10M..` works as expected for me with Emacs 27.0.50 and mu 1.2.0